# Unusual meaning of 考える

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension

> 歯を何回磨いたかなどをインターネットで歯医者に知らせて、虫歯にならないようにするサービスができました。歯ブラシなどの会社のサンスターと電気製品などの会社の富士通が**考えました**。
>   A service has been made that ensures you don't get tooth decay, by informing the dentist - using the internet - of things like how often you brush your teeth. Tooth brush making company サンスター and electrical goods company 富士通 *thought it up*.

I sometimes have trouble with 考える. This is one of those times. I'm not aware that 'thought it up' is a valid translation but it's the only one I can think of that fits the context. Have I got this right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「考{かんが}える」 has many meanings and in this context, it means "***to create something new***".

See definition #6 in [大辞林](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%80%83%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B%E3%83%BB%E5%8B%98%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B-236348#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88), which says:

> ⑥  工夫{くふう}して新{あたら}しいものを作{つく}る。

So, "thought it up" is a valid translation.

Comment: You might also mention ⑤ 計画する。意図する。in 大辞林.
**歯磨きデータをスマホで管理 予防歯科で新サービス** Original article in NHK" .歯磨き用品メーカー・サンスターと電機メーカー・富士通が共同で始めることになりました。"

Comment: ^ でも質問の引用文には「サービスができました。」 って書いてありますから、もうできたんですよね？もう「工夫して新しいサービスを作ったん」ですよね？ 「人材削減を考えている＝計画中だ・削減しようと意図している」のような、「サービスを計画中・しようと意図している」っていう状況じゃないですよね？

Comment: "工夫して新しいものを作る *to create something new*" could be said "考案{こうあん}する" for 考える in the sentence given by OP.